# How to generate all n-digit number in the n-digit-array way?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I know how to generate all n-digit number in the traditional number way,

```
for(long long number = pow(10, n-1); number < pow(10, n); number++) {
    cout << number << endl; 
}
```

for example,

```
for n = 5, it will generate 10000 to 99999;
```

However, since I will have to evaluate each number's digits, it is much convenient to construct the numbers in a digit array format in the first place.

for example, following code generate all 5-digit number in an array way:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            for(int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
                for(int m = 0; m < 9; m++) {
                    //executed 9 * 10^4 = 90000 times
                    //construct my array instance with i, j, k, l, m
                    cout << i << j << k << l << m << endl;      
                }
```

Now the problem is: n is unknown. (for example, it could be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..., 10)
Then how can I generate n-digit-array based on a number n?

For example, I want a piece of code like follows (any better ways than this one is highly appreciated):

```
for(int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    //each x is a layer of the loop ?!
    .....

}
```

Comment: I recommend storing just number array instead of storing each digit of all numbers.When you want to deal with specific number, just use statement like this:`while(n) { printf("%d", n % 10); n /= 10;}`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin why? Will use the statement on each of the number to convert to digit-array be faster than the permutation-like solution?

Comment: For less memory cost, if you just traverse the array once,there's no efficiency problem.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I've done an experiment and wrote as comment in Trevor's post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to limit ourselves to the range `0 - 9` for each digit of the number.
For each numerical place, we'll represent a range:

```
std::pair<int,int> range;
```

Each loop in your example is iterating from the beginning of the range to the end of the range.
All the loops together are really just a series of ranges; each nested loop being responsible for the next digit of your generated number.

We can represent that, in the following way:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ranges;
```

If you think about how nested `for loops` work, you can emulate the same functionality over the vector using two pointers.  I've done that and wrapped the functionality into a class:

```
//header
class Range_Combinator {

public:

  Range_Combinator(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> const &ranges_in);
  std::vector<int> Next();
  std::vector<int> Current();
  bool Done();

private:

  bool Adjust();
  void Reset_From_Current_Back(int from);

  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ranges;
  int current;
  int last;
  bool all_exausted;
  std::vector<int> current_vals;
};
```

---

```
//source
Range_Combinator::Range_Combinator(
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> const &ranges_in) {

  ranges = ranges_in;
  last = ranges.size() - 1;
  current = last;
  all_exausted = false;

  for (auto it : ranges) {
    current_vals.push_back(it.first);
  }
}

std::vector<int> Range_Combinator::Next() {
  all_exausted = Adjust();
  return current_vals;
}
std::vector<int> Range_Combinator::Current() { return current_vals; }

bool Range_Combinator::Done() { return all_exausted; }

bool Range_Combinator::Adjust() {
  if (current_vals[current] < ranges[current].second) {
    current_vals[current]++;
  } else {

    while (current_vals[current] == ranges[current].second) {
      current--;
    }

    if (current < 0) {
      return true;
    }

    Reset_From_Current_Back(current + 1);
    current_vals[current]++;
    current = last;
  }
  return false;
}

void Range_Combinator::Reset_From_Current_Back(int from) {

  for (int i = from; i <= last; ++i) {
    current_vals[i] = ranges[i].first;
  }
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
//create range combinator
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> ranges{{1,2},{3,4}};
Range_Combinator r(ranges);

//print each number
auto number = r.Current();
while (!r.Done()){
    for (auto it: number) std::cout << it; std::cout << '\n';
    number = r.Next();
}

//prints: 13
//        14
//        23
//        24
```

Comment: I did a compare between 1. get the number first iterate range "[ pow(10, N-1), pow(10, N) )" and then convert to digit array for each number; 2. this solution. If I just compute the digit-array, the time cost is "7s vs 5s"; If I compute digit-array and the number itself, the time cost is "7s vs 13s"; If I use your solution (to get the digit array only) and a parallel iteration started from pow(10, N-1), which will get the number only, combine the two, the time cost is 5s. (based on the fact that your solution is generating a increase sequence, exactly match the iteration).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need that but you can try this:

```
size_t n = ; //whatever value

unsigned char* x = new unsigned char[n]();
x[0] = 1;   //make it n-digit 10000...000
do
{
    //process digits here

    ++x[n - 1];
    for (size_t i = n; i > 1; --i)
    {
        if (x[i - 1] == 10)
        {
            x[i - 1] = 0;
            ++x[i - 2];
        }
    }
} while (x[0] < 10);

delete [] x;
```

You can even process not decimal numbers, just replace hard-coded 10 into appropriate number.

Comment: This is a straight forward implementation of how a 5-year child count to 1000 :), good. +1

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I could just write out the whole thing for you, but that would be no fun. Instead, I'll just outline the basic approach, and you can finish the answer yourself by filling in the blanks.

Consider an n-digit long number being represented this way:

```
 struct digit {
    struct digit *next;
    int n;    /* Digit 0-9 */
 };
```

A single number represented, in this manner, can be printed out this way:

```
void print_digit(struct digit *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        std::cout << p->n;
        p=p->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now, let's create a recursive loop, that iterates over all possible n-digit numbers:

```
void iterate(int ndigits)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        if (ndigits > 1)
        {
            iterate(ndigits-1);
        }
        else
        {   // This is the last digit

            // Here be dragons
        }
    }
}
```

After a bit of thinking, you can see that if, for example, you call `iterate(4)`, then when the "hear be dragons" part gets executed, this will be inside a four-deep nested iteration stack. There will be four level-deep `for` loops, nested within each other. And, with `iterate(6)`, there will be six of them, and so on.

Now, consider the fact that the `struct digit`-based representation of n-digit numbers is also a stack, of sorts.

Therefore, the homework assignment here would be to use this recursive iteration to dynamically construct this linked list, **on the stack**, with the "here be dragons" part simply invoking `print_digit()` in order to print each number.

Hint: `iterate()` will need to have a few more parameters, that it will use appropriately, with a certain preset value for them, on the initial call to iterate().

Answer (score 0):

A simple way without thinking of efficiency:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    int n = 3; // the number of digits
    long long start = 1;
    int *array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) start *= 10;
    for(long long x = start; x < start * 10; x++) { // not all 10-digit number will fit in 32-bit integer
        // get each digits in decimal, lowest digit in array[0]
        for (int i = 0, shift = 1; i < n; i++, shift *= 10) array[i] = (int)((x / shift) % 10);
        // do some work with it (print it here)
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) printf("%d", array[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the same as my pow(10, n-1) and pow(10, n) solution ---- number to digit-array; I'm actually more interested in finding a way to generate the digits directly ---- some permutation-like kind of thing for a given "n"